# Enrolling MOK certificate with dkms and virtualbox-dkms (Virtualbox with secure boot enabled)

Tags: virtualbox, secure-boot, dkms

As many others, I need to run a Windows instance from Virtualbox, don't want to disable Secure Boot, and therefore have problems in making Virtualbox work after kernel updates.

I have already run through the necessary steps, but something must have gone wrong. At present, Virtualbox runs if I disable secure boot, but freezes the whole system as soon as I try to run a VM (which at the moment is in an interrupted state) when secure boot is enabled.

I checked the following:

- I have generated a certificate (with `-subj "/CN=MyName/"`). A `MOK.der` is there, and I enrolled it (`mokutil --list-enrolled` shows it with another from Canonical). In fact if I try another `mokutil -n import MOK.der`, I get the output `SKIP: MOK.der is already enrolled`
- I am able to sign virtualbox modules by this script:

  ```
  <!-- language: bash -->
  #!/bin/bash
  for modfile in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/vbox*.ko; do
    echo "Signing $modfile"
    /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 \
                          /root/module-signing/MOK.priv \
                          /root/module-signing/MOK.der "$modfile"
  done
  ```
- ... and I can check that they are all signed:

  ```
  $ grep "MyName" $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/vbox*.ko 
  Il file binario /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko corrisponde
  Il file binario /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/vboxnetadp.ko corrisponde
  Il file binario /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/vboxnetflt.ko corrisponde
  Il file binario /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/vboxpci.ko corrisponde
  ```
- In fact I can load the modules from command line, with no error messages:
      $ for modfile in $(dirname $(modinfo -n vboxdrv))/vbox*.ko; do modprobe $(basename -s .ko $modfile); done
- Nevertheless, I can't find my certificate among those known at BIOS level: None of `mokutil --pk` , `mokutil --kek`, `mokutil --db`, includes "MyName" in the output (but some of them include "Canonical")

So, **the question**s:

- Where is the enrolled MOK stored if not in the PK, DB, or KEK? (in fact the modules *can* be loaded). Which name should I search for in my BIOS utility?
- What is *the shim*?
- I have `dkms` package installed, and only recently installed also `virtualbox-dkms`. Are these packages needed or not? In which sequence should I install them? before or after the above procedure? Or should they rather do the whole of it, instead of leaving it to be done by me *manually*?
- Should I rather try uninstalling `virtualbox`, `dkms`, `virtualbox-dkms` (etc?) and redo the procedure from scratch?
- What of the above remains applicable fopr the rest of the modules in the `/lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms` directory (namely `bbswitch` and `nvidia*`)? In fact, from the System Settings menu, under System/Software & Updates I see that the Nvidia 384.111 proprietary driver is being used, but then I can neither see it by `lsmod | grep nvidia` nor `modprobe` it:

  ```
  $ modprobe nvidia_384
  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_384': Required key not available
  ```

Is the situation inconsistent? Where to start from to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: btw, I now *discovered* that `sbin/vboxconfig` makes modules and saves them in `/var/lib/dkms/`, while all instructions and code snippets will do the signing in `/lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/`, and the two are not symlinked... Am I signing the right modules?

Comment: ... and..., what should I check about consistency of version of packages, as I have virtualbox-5.2, dkms, virtualbox-dkms, etc? How to get back to a fresh install?