# How do I abort "Configuring Secure Boot" with anbox installation?

Tags: kernel, 18.10, secure-boot, anbox

I wanted to install anbox, which requires the `anbox-modules-dkms` package.

During this package installation a prompt appears on the terminal with a message saying it will guide you through the secure boot configuration, and there is only one option to choose: "OK". At this point I realized I really don't want to be messing with my boot/kernel right now, so I decided to abort, but the only way to quit the prompt is killing the apt process (next step after clicking "OK" is creating a password). If I do so, next time I need to use apt-get I will have to fix it first using `dpkg --configure -a`, the problem is this resumes `anbox-modules-dkms` installation and the prompt appears again.

How do I stop the module configuration, remove it entirely, and repair my system state (I don't want dpkg --configure -a to bring it up again)

Comment: If you don't want to configure, disable it - Secure Boot - instead.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia nonono - I have a secure computer that does not have a complete backup system. I want to install other items now, but don't want this module.

Comment: Secure Boot is a UEFI feature, independent of the OS. It does prevent booting unsigned kernels, drivers, etc. If you want to keep it enabled then you must manually sign whatever modules you want to install. This and what I mentioned in the first comment are your only options. Your choice.

Comment: I don't want to install this module. How do I stop the process and restore my system?

Comment: Stop what exactly? Please [edit] because the question isconfusing]

Comment: Tried to edit for clarity. I just want `anbox-modules-dkms` to disappear somehow

Comment: Install it then remove it, it's that simple.

Comment: Ok - so the only way is forward. Being moderately skillful, I've had my fair share of un-bootable systems and un-accessible hard drives from using "standard" (ubuntu) tooling. I'll just have to get a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

I am handling this issue (in Ubuntu 16.04) by commenting out relevant parts in 
`/var/lib/dpkg/info/shim-signed.postinst` and `/usr/sbin/dkms` but looking for a more permanent way.

My system has secure boot enabled, I have own key, sign updated modules before rebooting. Yet the dpkg part keeps insisting that a new MOK needs to be enrolled in the firmware. For both Virtualbox as well as for Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the update of my answer and other suggestions. Created a new question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173767/ taking a risk it could be considered related/duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017338. That one is very old and generic, I have a short and specific request instead.